# Cannot Send Email via Webform Drupal 7

Tags: php, email, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I've setup my webform without any configurations other than adding the right fields and recipients to send once the form is submitted. I run a test on my local server and our actual server and both did not send the information needed. The form redirects to itself instead of the confirmation page I set.

I made the following tests to insure that this is a Drupal issue:

- **Created a test mail.php** on the server and **it was successful.**
- Enabled **contact module in Drupal core**, and **sent a successful test email.**
- **Requested password to check** if it will send. **It failed to send.**
- **Filled up the webform I created and submitted** but **did not send to the provided email.**

Does anyone know what the issue is? What seems to be the problem? I cannot seem to find why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it seems like it having issue with sending email.
It is either having configuration problem so it will not able to connect SMTP host OR 
You haven't setup SMTP server configuration yet.

For SMTP server configuration:

- Download [PHPMAILER](https://drupal.org/project/phpmailer)
- [Please read carefully this instructions](http://drupalcode.org/project/phpmailer.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/README.txt)

You need SMTP server configuration to setup send email....

You can either use GMIAL/HOTMAIL server use SMTP hosting provider like TurboSMTP...

Hope this will help you...